# inheritance in python - how to make a method both a classmethod and a regular method?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, static-methods

Suppose I have a method in a class whose structure is as follows:

```
class TestClass(object):
   ...
   def __init__(self, ...)
       ...
       self.var1 = ...
       self.var2 = ...
       ...
   ...
   def xyz(self, other)
       if isinstance(other, TestClass):
            ...
            self.var1 = ...
            ...
       else:
            ...
            self.var2 = ...
            ...
```

Now suppose I want to write another class `NewTestClass` that inherits from `TestClass` (i.e. `class NewTestClass(TestClass): ...` ).

One issue with the method `xyz` is that it explicitly checks the `other` variable if it was an instance of `TestClass` AND it also refers to attributes of the instance (i.e `self.var1`, `self.var2`).

(a) How can I rewrite method `xyz` so that, upon inheritance (in `NewTestClass`), the `if` statement behaves like `if isinstance(other, NewTestClass): ...` (and I don't have to rewrite a method `xyz` within `NewTestClass`)?

(b) Similarly, suppose I have another `method` in `TestClass` that refers to a `staticmethod` in `TestClass`, for instance:

```
@staticmethod
def abc(x):
    ...
    val = ...
    ...
    return val

def mnp(self, ...):
    ...
    x1 = ...
    self.var1 = TestClass.abc(x1)
    ...
```

Here, the method `mnp` uses `staticmethod` of `TestClass` (i.e. `TestClass.abc` in this example). How can I rewrite `TestClass.abc`, so that when the `NewTestClass` inherits `TestClass`, it gets a method `mnp` that treats the `self.var =` line as equivalent of `self.var1 = NewTestClass.abc(x1)` (and I don't have to rewrite a method `mnp` within `NewTestClass`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

```
def xyz(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
       ...
```

b) you can call the static class method with `self`:

```
    def mnp(self, ...):
        ....
        self.var1 = self.abc(...)
```

Comment: sorry I didn't realize you answered before. thanks for answering and I marked your answer. I upvoted both you and @lockey. also, what would be the equivalent of `isinstance(x, TestClass)` inside a `classmethod` ? Should I write `isinstance(x, cls.__class__)` or `isinstance(x, cls)` ?

Comment: I would say, `isinstance(x, cls)` but I didn't test myself

Answer (score 2):

For part (a), you need to check whether `other` is an instance of the same class as `self`:

```
class TestClass(object):
  def xyz(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
      ...
      self.var1 = ...
      ...
    else:
      ...
      self.var2 = ...
      ...
```

It's normally considered more 'pythonic' to avoid `isinstance` for this kind of logic, where possible. Consider using Python's duck typing. The following example won't be exactly what you need, because both of the attributes exist in your class. However, if you choose an appropriate exception for your real code, this technique will work.

```
class TestClass(object):
  def xyz(self, other):
    try:
      self.var1 = ...   # The minimum code required to raise the exception
    except AttributeError:
      self.var2 = ...
    else:
      pass              # Any other code if the exception is not raised
```

Python's exception handling is lightweight and is intended to be used in this way. It makes your code more resilient if something unexpected (possibly not yet even considered) is passed in.

For part (b), you don't need to specify the class when calling a static method. It can be called on an instance (`self`) instead.

```
class TestClass(object):
  @staticmethod
  def abc(x):
    return x  # Do something useful

  def mnp(self, x):
    self.var1 = self.abc(x)
```

Now when you declare a new static method in the derived class, it will be called correctly:

```
class NewTestClass(TestClass):
  @staticmethod
  def abc(x):
    return x * 2  # Do something else useful

a = NewTestClass()
a.mnp(1)
assert a.var1 == 2  # because NewTestClass.abc was called by mnp
```

Comment: what could be the equivalent of `isinstance(x, TestClass)` inside a `classmethod` ? Should I write `isinstance(x, cls.__class__)` or `isinstance(x, cls)` ?

Comment: It's `isinstance(x,cls)` as @mguijarr says above. `cls.__class__` is `type` (see documentation for metaclasses)

Answer (score 0):

You can do ugly reflection stuff to make it work, but that's not the right thing to do. If the classes suppose to extend one another naturally - do it, if not - don't.

That said, one thing you can do, is to change the current implementation, instead of assigning a var - to call another function that do so, and implement this function in each class to modify the correct variable.

For example, change:

```
def xyz(self, other)
   if isinstance(other, TestClass):
        ...
        self.var1 = ...
        ...
   else:
        ...
        self.var2 = ...
        ...
```

to:

```
def xyz(self, other)
   if isinstance(other, TestClass):
        ...
        self.modifyVar(value)
        ...
   else:
        ...
        self.var2 = ...
        ...
```

and then in one class you'll implement:

```
def modifyVar(self, value):
    self.var1 = value
```

and in another class you'll have:

```
def modifyVar(self, value):
    self.var2 = value
```

This answer covers both cases (static and non-static functions).

Comment: not sure if you understood my question. I want to change the line `if isinstance(other, TestClass)` to behave as if it is `if isinstance(other, TestClass)` within `TestClass` and as if it is `if isinstance(other, NewTestClass)` within `NewTestClass` which is an inheritance of `TestClass`. I'm not really bother about `self.var1` or `self.var2` - for all I care the two lines could have been doing anything that needs an instance

Comment: So change it to: `if isinstance(other, TestClass) or isinstance(other, NewTestClass):`

Comment: what if, in the future, I create more subclasses - `ModifiedTestClass`, `AnotherTestClass` ? I will have to keep on changing the code within `TestClass` if I do what you suggest ...

Comment: @uday it's easier to add try/except for each class than add `isinstance` check ? Personally - I don't like neither solutions. I would solve it by creating another function that will be inherited by all the classes: `isATestClass()` and which always returns true. I think that it will be much cleaner.